# No se muestra imagen extraída de google drive HTML

Tags: php, html, html-select, diseño

Estoy intentando cargar una imagen desde **drive** solo con el fin de ver como se muestra en el *explorador* pero **solo me sale el icono de una foto**.

Este es el código:

```html
<!doctype html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>Firma HTML</title>  
    </head>
    
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=14c67W8sWwKRJShrj14ab3uu6fatSYx6g"/>
    
         
    </html>
```

Comment: Si intentas acceder directamente a esa url da un error 400. El icono que ves es porque reconoce el elemento <img> seguramente, pero no hay foto en esa url, al menos ahora ya no (quizas era algo temporal)

Answer (score 0):

El patrón actual definido por Google para mostrar imágenes embebidas es el siguiente:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=IDIMAGEN
```

Simplemente, sustituye `IDIMAGEN` por el valor del ID de la imagen que quieres mostrar.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.container img {
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=14c67W8sWwKRJShrj14ab3uu6fatSYx6g"/>
</div>
```

#### Recomendación

De todos modos, considera que a lo largo del tiempo Google ha cambiado la forma de mostrar imágenes, por lo que sería conveniente que implementes la API de Google para este tipo de operaciones, pues si Google cambia en un futuro este patrón de URL por otro, las imágenes dejarán de verse.

Si son muchas imágenes, en muchas partes de tu aplicación, mientras implementas la API de Google, puedes declarar una constante con este valor `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=` y usar dicha constante. Así, si Google cambia, tú cambias nada más la constante, así no tendrás que ir a buscar en todos los contenidos donde pusiste ese valor manualmente.

Precisamente, otra de las ventajas del uso de APIs es que te ayuda a tener el código más centralizado, automatizado siendo más fácil de mantener (aparte de las ventajas que las APIs en sí mismas ya te proporcionan).